# Two different solution for integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a problem with integrating the function f:

```
f=(Sqrt[0.9079451035686734 + (-2.0942769313788814 + x)*x]*(-0.0000446835054402416 + 
   x*(0.0005613035192645842 + x*(-0.0015376466772624837 + 
       x*(-0.0014475032958119315 + x*(-0.00377181605950115 + x*(0.030477293910792964 + 
             x*(-0.044503978291737425 + x*(0.03344713255566077 + (0.0010028169124785074 - 
                   0.007096111759868821*x)*x)))))))))/
 (x^3*(0.9079451035686734 + x*(-2.0942769313788814 + 1.*x))^2);
\[Eta] = 1.777^2/4.546^2;
\[Rho] = 0.987^2/4.546^2;
```

When I integrate over f in this way i get:

```
Integrate[f, {x, \[Eta], (1 - Sqrt[\[Rho]])^2}, 
 GenerateConditions -> False] = 21042.9
```

However, when I integrate it this way i obtain:

```
Integrate[f, x, GenerateConditions -> False];
(% /. x -> (1 - Sqrt[\[Rho]])^2) - (% /. x -> \[Eta]) = -0.0167203 - 205520. I
```

Anybody knows whats going on here

Comment: `Integrate[f, {x, \[Eta], (1 - Sqrt[\[Rho]])^2},  GenerateConditions -> False]`  returns -0.0207141 + 0.00224015 I in Mathematica 13.0. It's probably the branch cuts - if you look at your antiderivative `Integrate[f, x]` you've got `Log` and `Sqrt` in there.

Comment: The two need not be equal, for reasons given by @flinty. SO the short answer might be "Nothing". As in, "Nothing is going on here".

Answer (score 6):

It is a precision issue. Use [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) to convert all numeric values to exact values.

```
f = (Sqrt[
       0.9079451035686734 + (-2.0942769313788814 + x)*
         x]*(-0.0000446835054402416 + 
        x*(0.0005613035192645842 + 
           x*(-0.0015376466772624837 + 
              x*(-0.0014475032958119315 + 
                 x*(-0.00377181605950115 + 
                    x*(0.030477293910792964 + 
                    x*(-0.044503978291737425 + 
                    x*(0.03344713255566077 + (0.0010028169124785074 - 
                    0.007096111759868821*x)*
                    x)))))))))/(x^3*(0.9079451035686734 + 
         x*(-2.0942769313788814 + 1.*x))^2) // Rationalize[#, 0] &;

η = 1.777^2/4.546^2 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;

ρ = 0.987^2/4.546^2 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;

Integrate[N[f, 75], {x, η, (1 - Sqrt[ρ])^2}] // N // Chop

(* 210485. *)

Integrate[N[f, 75], x, GenerateConditions -> False];
(% /. x -> (1 - Sqrt[ρ])^2) - (% /. x -> η) // N // Chop

(* 210485. *)
```